# Upload form max_size in php

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I have an upload form like this.

```
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" value="file"/>
<input type="submit" value="UPLAOD" name="upload"/><br/>
</body>
```

and upload.php as:

```
if($_FILES["file"]["error"]>0)
     echo "ERROR: ".$_FILES["file"]["error"]."<br/>";
else{
     if(file_exists("./".$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        echo "File already exists.";
    else
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"./".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "File Uploaded.";
    }
    }
```

I changed the `upload_max_filesize=10M , post_max_size=8M` in `php.ini`
But i still cant upload a file of 5MB size. What might have gone wrong ?

when i run `phpinfo()`, it still shows `upload_max_size=2M` which was the value before i changed it to `10M`.

Comment: Have you restarted your webservice?

Comment: Are you on a shared hosting which prevents you from updating these values?

Comment: not shared hosting....just for learning purposes. i am using WAMP

Comment: ohh yes. restarting helped. thanks a lot.
and for knowledge sakes, what is the maximum upload limits can we give..?/

Answer (score 2):

Try this [link](http://drupal.org/node/97193)

> to increase the limit on uploaded files to 10 MB:
>
> Add the below to the relevant php.ini file (recommended, if you have
>   access). Note that for some hosts this is a system-wide setting.
>   However, for hosts running PHP as a CGI script with suexec (for
>   example) you may be able to put these directives in a php.ini file in
>   your Drupal root directory.
>
> - upload_max_filesize = 10M
> - post_max_size =10M
>
> Add the below to your .htaccess file in your Drupal root
>   directory.
>
> - php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
> - php_value post_max_size
>     10M

There are quite a few articles out there on this

Answer (score 2):

For uploading large sized files please refer the steps mentioned below.

1) Create a .htaccess file in the root folder of web server.

2) Put the following code into .htaccess file.

**php_value upload_max_filesize 20M**

**php_value post_max_size 20M**

**php_value max_execution_time 200**

**php_value max_input_time 200**